# Why are lots of updates occurring at the exact same time in a calendar list?

Tags: 2007, calendar

We are having a problem with several of our SharePoint calendar lists where a huge (200+) number of items are somehow getting updated at exactly the same time.  This puts these events into the "Pending" state even though the update did not change any fields (visible, at least).  The individuals who are listed as the "Modified By" user deny making these changes, and in at least one case the user was out of the office.

What could be causing this problem?  My suspicion is Outlook integration.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook integration could definitely be a culprit.  Is the calendar all out of the box?  Or do you have some custom event receivers or workflows attached to the calendar that may be looping or updating all items instead of an intended single item?

Comment: One has very extensive event receivers and no workflow.  Another has neither event receivers or workflows.  The third I am unsure of as I only have view permissions on it.

Comment: I would look into what those event receivers are doing.  Just a thought.

Comment: The event receivers on the calendar one calendar definitely does not touch the other two calendars - in fact, one of the other calendars is on a different web app entirely.

Comment: I may be out of ideas then.  I've never seen that sort of behavior out of the box.  It is not out of the question that a workflow or event receiver from another web app is the culprit.  My overall point is that it seems that somewhere there is custom code that is doing this.  Perhaps looking at the SharePoint logs and/or IIS traffic logs could shed some light.